# What to get the data From a column based on the JSON Tag Stored in the Column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table which stores the Data as JSON file name in one column and Full JSON on the Other Column.

lets say col1 has **data.json** and 
col 2 has JSON in it
 `{ "ID": "1", "Name": "ABC", "Dept":"market" }`

I want to Build a Query where i can get the name from JSON on the basis of ID, Consider below as an example for the query which I want

```
select (SHOULD GIVE JSON TAG **NAME**) from temp where col1=data.json and col2 (JSON ID is 1)
```

It should Return **ABC** for the Above JSON Stored in Col2.

Comment: Is it hive or oracle? Don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak Removed it but Query is almost same in Hive and Oracle. If u can suggest something in Oracle. It can be framed for Hive too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hive, you could use the `get_json_object` function.

```
SELECT get_json_object(col2, '$.Name') AS Name
FROM TEMP
WHERE col1 = 'data.json'
    AND get_json_object(col2, '$.ID') = 1;
```